# disable cups to specific users

Tags: printing, iptables

I used the command below to disable cups for a specific user, but it did not work!

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -m owner --uid-owner username -j DROP
```

Any one has an idea? or has another solution to disable cups?

Comment: If you do not want some users to print, you may use the configuraton in `cups` (e.g. via the web administration page).

Comment: how can I do that. Give me sample if you can

Comment: In browser enter `http://<servername-or-ip>:631/admin`; from there select `manage printers`. In the page related to the printer select `Administration->Set Allowed Users`. Here you can disallow users to use the printer. For more information, see the `Help`pages.

Comment: I want to prevent a specific user from accessing this page of cups. How !